# What happens to the mount namespace of an interrupted process

Tags: linux, mount, namespace

I am experimenting with mount namespaces. I have a python script, which creates a bind mount, after that a mount namespace with the `unshare` system call. I print the PID, and pause the script. I can list the mounts with:

```
nsenter --mount=/proc/PID/ns/mnt
mount
```

Let the python process be interrupted before calling `umount` (or let us say it terminates due to some error). Now `/proc/PID` disappears. Will the system be in a consistenst state? I mean will `umount` be called automatically, or will the mounts "cleaned up" some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mount namespace, like any other namespace, is removed once all its member processes exit (unless it is kept alive via a bind mount: see `man 7 namespaces`, search for “Bind mounting”), and when a mount point is removed, all its mounts are implicitly unmounted, see `man 7 mount_namespaces`:

> A mount ceases to be a member of a peer group when … the mount is implicitly unmounted because a mount namespace is removed (because it has no more member processes).